# M2 | sales email > customize price display > how to show only grand totals?

Tags: magento2, price, email, order-email

I'm trying to style Magento's transactional emails.
I already managed it to edit and style the item display and included the item picture, but i haven't found a solution to only display the grandTotal price including tax and style it.

[image: how to only display Grand Total and style it?]

Customizing items was quite easy by creating an own `/email/items/order/default.phtml`. but I couldn't find a file, which generates the price display.

My Magento skills are quite basic. I would be glad for any advice as detailed as possible.

Comment: Did you find this? The solution below also updates areas in checkout and my history page - is there no phtml block only?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid Not really. I think you have to build you own totals block and include it as custom variable in the email template.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but I think this might work:

Copy over Magento_Sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml with the one line added like below:

```
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php if ($_code !== 'grand_total') continue; // add this line ?>
```

You should be able to add styling in this file as well.

Comment: Thank you Aaron! We're almost there...
Actually only the price excluding tax gets displayed. I need the price incl. tax .

Comment: So what field is it showing? If it's "Grand Total", that amount does have the sales tax included.

Comment: Sry for my late response. Unfortunately it's showing the total price excluding tax, not including tax.

Comment: This edits the code on every page where their is totals